# Passing parameter to onchange event in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a select tag in my rails app, and i want to call showSubTypes function function onchange event

```html
<%= f.select :type, RequestType.all.collect {
         |p| [p.typeName, p.id] }, {include_blank: true },
         :onchange => 'showSubTypes()'  %>
```

Here i want to pass p.id parameter into my showSubtypes function. But i do not know how to do that in rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you can add in `application.js` this code

```
$(function () {
   // specify id or class for your select tag   
   $('select').on('change', function () {
        console.log($(this).val());            // get option value
        console.log($(this).text());           // get option text
        showSubTypes($(this).val());
   });
});
```

If you use jQuery you don't need use *inline events*

And in your template

```
<%= f.select :type, RequestType.all.collect {|p| [p.typeName, p.id]}, {include_blank: true } %>
```