# Passing parameter to onchange of select in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

```html
<%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(
              @rtypes, "id", "typeName"), 
              {include_blank: true },                                                
:onchange => ShowSubTypes() %>
```

Here I have options for select, what I want is to pass an id as a parameter to `ShowSubTypes()` function. My `@rtypes` variable returns an array, therefore I cant just pass `@rtypes.id`.

Comment: change your onchange to `:onchange => "ShowSubTypes(#{whatever_you_want_to_pass_through.inspect})"`

Comment: @user3565829 have you seen this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28896091/passing-parameter-to-onchange-event-in-rails/28896149#28896149

Comment: Presumably you want to pass the _selected_ id into `ShowSubTypes` ?

Comment: @ThongKuah , yep, thats is exactly what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :id, options_from_collection_for_select(
              @rtypes, "id", "typeName"), 
              {include_blank: true },                                                                                                           
:onchange => "ShowSubTypes($(this).val())" %>
```

Basically you can accomplish this via Javascript. `this` within the context of the onChange is the `<select>` input. I have assumed jQuery to obtain the value of the selected option which corresponds to "id" of @rtypes.

In plain Javascript, I think it's `this.value`